# Clustering Coefficient for Directed Graph

Tags: python, igraph, networkx, graph-theory

There are two definitions for **digraph** (local) clustering coefficient.
One is based on the number of links in one node's neighbourhood([defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient#Local_clustering_coefficient)) and another is based on the number of triangles through one node([defined in networkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html#networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering)). I wonder do they return the same values as nodes' clustering coefficients?
And is there any efficient and permanent implementation in python? (networkx and igraph did not implemented clustering coefficient for digraphs)

Comment: Are you talking about [centrality](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html#module-networkx.algorithms.centrality) measures? Degree would be the number of connections to a particular node (weighted if applicable) or any number of other scoring metrics

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, I am trying to calculate a custom **centrality** formula that is something like `Centrality_u = Betweenness_u / total_number_of_edges_between_neighbors_of_u`

Comment: Sounds like something like calculating the betweeness, then creating a `subgraph` centered on `u`, and calculating the degree. Beyond that, though, I would recommend a)looking through the existing centrality measures to see if any of them match what you want, and b)trying some things and asking specific questions if you get stuck, once you have some code